# c# Sorting Console input array Sorting system broken

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, int

I've been working on a console application that gets input from the user and converts it into an Array, which is then sorted and displayed back to the user. The problem is that it only seems to grab half of the numbers and sorts those. and it also sometimes doesn't grab the "End" input, which results in the application failing. Why does this happen?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Int64> userInts = new List<Int64>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            int userInt;
            if (int.TryParse(userValue, out userInt))
            {
                userInts.Add(userInt);
                if (Console.ReadLine().Contains("End"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        Int64[] Numbers = userInts.ToArray();
        var intList = new List<Int64>();
        intList.AddRange(Numbers);
        Console.WriteLine("De originele opsteling van nummers:");
        foreach (Int64 numb in intList)
            Console.Write("    {0}", numb);
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        intList.Sort();
        Console.WriteLine("Lijst in gesorteerde ordening:  ");
        foreach (Int64 numb in intList)
            Console.Write("    {0}", numb);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: TryParse will return false, because End can not be converted to integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will ignore every other line looking for `End`, move that outside of the nested `if` block so the entered value can be processed.

```
List<Int64> userInts = new List<Int64>();
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userValue.Contains("End"))
    {
        break;
    }

    int userInt;
    if (int.TryParse(userValue, out userInt))
    {
        userInts.Add(userInt);
    }
}
```

---

Also your second block of code where you sort your list can be made simpler.

```
Console.WriteLine("De originele opsteling van nummers:");
Console.Write(string.Join("    ", userInts));
Console.WriteLine();
userInts.Sort();
Console.WriteLine("Lijst in gesorteerde ordening:");
Console.Write(string.Join("    ", userInts));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadKey();
```

- You do not need multiple arrays or lists, just use the `userInts` variable that you already have
- Use [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a string of values instead of looping
- There is no need to pass `Environment.NewLine` to `Console.WriteLine()`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading twice inside your loop - so the input gets only captured every second time, either in the first or the second ReadLine, causing the behavior you describe.

Something like this should work :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userValue.Contains("End"))
            {
                break;
            }
        int userInt;
        if (int.TryParse(userValue, out userInt))
        {
            userInts.Add(userInt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Console.ReadLine().Contains("End"))
{
    break;
}
```

This will read line. If it was "End" - then it will stop program, but if it was integer - that will be discarded.

For the same reason, as it is in the `if` condition for `TryParse`, it will only End program if had integer that was previously parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using so many lists? You can use one :)

Try this:

```
List<long> userInts = new List<long>();
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userValue.Contains("End"))
        break;

    int userInt;

    if (int.TryParse(userValue, out userInt))
        userInts.Add(userInt);

}

// Print the unchanged numbers
Console.WriteLine("De originele opsteling van nummers:");
foreach (long numb in userInts)
    Console.Write("    {0}", numb);

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
// Sorts the List
userInts.Sort();

// Output the sorted list
Console.WriteLine("Lijst in gesorteerde ordening:  ");
foreach (long numb in userInts)
    Console.Write("    {0}", numb);

Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadKey();
```